# How to control the memory usage of processes spawned by a JVM

Tags: java, memory, controls, process, native

I am coding an application that creates JVMs and needs to control the memory usage of the processes spawned by the JVM.

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? Please elaborate

Comment: Exact memory allocated by the process?  Or is -Xmx for heap good enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to JVM process using JMX to get information about memory status / allocations and also provoke garbage collection. But you first need to enable JMX monitoring of your JVM: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are talking about non-Java "processes" spawned using `Runtime.exec(...)` etc.

The answer is that this is OS specific and not something that the standard Java libraries support.  But if you were going to do this in Linux (or UNIX) I can think of three approaches:

- Have Java spawn the command via a shell wrapper script that uses the `ulimit` builtin to reduce the memory limits, then `exec`s the actual command; see `man 1 ulimit`.
- Write a little C command that does the same as the shell wrapper. This will have less overhead than the wrapper script approach.
- Try to do the same with JNI and a native code library.  Not recommended because you'd probably need to replicate the behavior of `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`, and that could be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'control' you mean 'limit to a known upper bound', then you can simply pass

```
-Xms`lower_bound`
```

and

```
-Xmx`upper_bound`
```

to the vm's args when you spawn the process. [see the approproate setting here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

Comment: The question is not about JVM heap memory but a process system memory spawned by JVM (separate process)